# polynomial with nonzero coefficients at prime degree terms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that there is a non-zero polynomial $Q(x)$ with integer coefficients, such that the product
>   $$P(x)Q(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k x^k$$
>   has only nonzero coefficients at the prime degree terms. In other words, $a_k=0$ if $k$ is not a prime.

For binomial $P(x)$ it is equivalent to the existence of infinitely many primes in an arithmetic progression. But I don't know how to go further.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you read this anymore after so many years, but can you explain HOW this is equivalent to the existence of infinitely many primes in arithmetic progressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $d=\deg P$. Then the $\mathbb Q$-vector space $V=\mathbb Q[X]/(P)$ is $d$-dimensional. The residue classes modulo $(P)$ of $X^2,X^3,X^5,\dots$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q$, so there exist $a_2,a_3,a_5,\ldots\in\mathbb Z$ not all zero such that $a_2X^2+a_3X^3+a_5X^5+\cdots\in(P).$ This shows that there is $Q\in\mathbb Z[X]$, $Q\ne0$ such that $PQ=a_2X^2+a_3X^3+a_5X^5+\cdots$.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that the "prime" condition is note essential at all.